# Slide up a div on hover over and show the Contact button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build this functionality:

http://www.liveyourdream.org/take-action/index.html

So when a box is hovered over, the contact button show under the box as the box is sliding up.  I tried mouseenter and mouseleave methods, it kinda works but not exactly as how I want. Of course on mouseleave the box slides back down, but I want the box to stay up so the user can click the Contact button.

```
<div class="container top">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Opportunity title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Opportunity description, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eget magna consectetur, ultrices sem ac, ultricies dolor. Vivamus eget venenatis nulla. Nunc vitae purus mi. Fusce sed iaculis massa.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>          
    </div>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Contact</a>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and:

```
$('.card-block').mouseenter(function() {
   $('.card-block').animate({top: -20}, 5);
});
$('.card-block').mouseleave(function() {
   $('.card-block').animate({top: 20}, 5);
});
```

Here's what I've done so far https://jsfiddle.net/eykg89js/

The Contact button should be at the bottom of the Card. I am also using Bootstrap. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of transitioning `margin` transition `transform: translateY()` instead, so that the element will still occupy the space on the page that it did pre-`translateY()` transform. Give the card a background color so that you can't see the hidden content underneath. No need for a `z-index` on the hidden `p`, just move it before the card in your HTML. Remove the default `margin` on the `p`, and use `left` and `right` values of `15px` to offset the padding from bootstrap's col class padding.

```css
.top {margin-top: 60px;}
.card-block {transition: 0.5s ease; background: white;}
.card-container:hover .card-block { cursor: pointer; transform: translateY(-30px); }
.info {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:15px;
  right: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 card-container">
          <p class="info">More info here</p>
          <div class="card card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Opportunity title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Opportunity description, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eget magna consectetur, ultrices sem ac, ultricies dolor. Vivamus eget venenatis nulla. Nunc vitae purus mi. Fusce sed iaculis massa.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Michael, it looks good. So, are you recommending pure CSS and no JS?  Also, when the card slides back down as soon as the mouse is hovering out to click the "More info here".  I want to mimic the exact behavior as liveyourdream website.

Comment: I added some jQuery, it works but it's a little jumpy on hover out (mouseleave): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpKbzP  any idea how to improve it to make it look more like the example?

Comment: @Marz ah, modified my answer to trigger the card movement by hovering the parent rather than hovering the card itself. No need for JS. CSS is more performant and simpler. Transition on the `transform` property gets GPU acceleration, so it's smooth and performant.

Comment: Awesome! it looks great and it's smooth :)